# pygame will not load my game when i run it?

Tags: python, 2d, pygame, python-idle

I am currently making a basic 2D platform game and all I have made so far is the background for the start menu. But when I run it does not run my game. Once in a while it will run it and everything will show up but there is a black block covering part of the window?

Can someone explain why this is?

```
bif=("cloud.jpg")

import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((813,555),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Red Dwarf')

background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))


pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: my code has not full shown up here but is starts at bif=("cloud.jpg"). sorry

Comment: have you tried inserting any `print` statements in your code at various stages to see what's happening?

Comment: "I am currently making a basic 2D platform game and all I have made so far is the background for the start menu" - that's gold right there!

Answer (score 1):

As I answered in your other question already: Indendation...!

Your pygame.display.update() is outside the while loop. This means that it is not called until the while loop has finished and that's not going to happen here, therefore the display is just never ever updated.

Indend the pygame.display.update() to the level of screen.blit(background,(0,0)) and it will work just fine.